# Codeigniter - Regex Expression to include a period - preg_match

Tags: regex, codeigniter, validation, preg-match

I have a regex expression as follows:

```
return ( ! preg_match("/^([-a-z_ -])+$/i", $str)) ? FALSE : TRUE;
```

I need to add to it to allow a period, so that the input could be something like this:

"st. austell" or "st. thomas"

I have tried various ways to add the period to the above rule, but the page either crashes out and just displays a blank page, or my validation errors are triggered.

I have tried things like this, but to no avail.

```
([-a-z_ -.])
([-a-z_ -\.])
([-a-z_ -])\.
(\.[-a-z_ -]) etc etc...
```

I have tried everything and don't seem to bee having any luck - any ideas

Many Thanks

James

Comment: The initial regex is redundant, since it specifies `-` twice. Moreover, `[a-z_ .-]` should work, you just have to let `a-z` together and `-` just after `[` or just before `]`. Finally, `return !condition ? false : true;` should be simplified to `return condition;`, since `condition` already returns `true` or `false`.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this now: /^([a-z_ .-])+$/i and I still just get a white page with no content - if I remove the . the page comes back again - any ideas? I have tried to escape the period as well but it still does not work

Comment: Sorry, my bad, there was a typo - thanks sp00m - you've got it!

Comment: @sp00m That looks a lot like an answer... why dont you post it as such so dBD can officially acknowledge your regex wisdom

Answer (score 1):

Three points:

1. The initial regex is redundant, since it specifies `-` twice.
2. `[a-z_ .-]` should work, you just have to let `a-z` together and `-` just after `[` or just before `]` (otherwise, `-` will be considered as a metachar).
3. `return !condition ? false : true;` should be simplified to `return condition;`, since `condition` already returns `true` or `false` (same logic for `if(!condition) {var = false;} else {var = true;}` which should be simplified to `var = condition;`).